# Обновить Git на десктопе Win7x64

Tags: git

Установленный только что VS Code начал просить обновить Git - он у меня версии 1.9.4... и стоит в папке C:\RS\Git. Ставился где-то год назад вместе с RailsInstaller'oм.

[Обнаружил](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790592/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-of-git-on-windows-still-showing-older-vers), что, начиная с версии Git 2.16.1(2) его можно обновить, просто введя в командную строку `git update-git-for-windows`.

Однако у меня рабочая версия гита намного более древняя и с ней этот трюк не проходит.

Что нужно сделать? Полностью снести старую версию и просто установить самую последнюю?

Comment: Удалите и установите новый, не морочьте себе мозги